# UGC comments and ratings data not available in Control Room

Tags: 2013-sp1, ugc

We have setup the UGC on our SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 environment and we are able to add and view comments (both from the website and from the CM) as well as submit and retrieve ratings from the website.

However, we are not able to see the UGC comments and ratings data for the analytics in the CME Control Room:

[image]

If I open the page or the component in CME on which comments and ratings have been provided - I can see a list of all of them in the Comments and Ratings tab respectively:
[image]

I have checked all logs (Tridion Event Logs and UGC Services logs) but could not see anything related.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Has the user access to the relevant publication(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that, when you open the filter options, and select the publications where comments are added, you will see all comments and ratings for those publications.

Comment: Thanks Harald...yes it is a bit of weird UX that you need to filter first to see all results - the expectation for UX perspective seems to be to show all data and then filter as per the need